# Is it possible to make this grammar unambiguous? expr: ... | expr expr

Tags: formal-grammars, ambiguity

I am writing a simple calculator in *yacc* / *bison*.

The grammar for an expression looks somewhat like this:

```
expr
: NUM
| expr '+' expr { $$ = $1 + $3; }
| expr '-' expr { $$ = $1 - $3; }
| expr '*' expr { $$ = $1 * $3; }
| expr '/' expr { $$ = $1 / $3; }
| '+' expr %prec '*' { $$ = $1; }
| '-' expr %prec '*' { $$ = $1; }
| '(' expr ')' { $$ = $2; }
| expr expr { $$ = $1 '*' $2; }
;
```

I have declared the precedence and associativity of the operators like this.

```
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
%nonassoc '('
```

The problem is with the last rule:

```
expr expr { $$ = $1 $2; }
```

I want this rule because I want to be able to write expressions like `5(3+4)(3-24)` in my calculator.

Is it possible to make this grammar unambiguous?

Comment: Try adding `%prec '*'` or some other precedence to this rule.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: That can't work. By the time `expr expr` has been reached, the damage has been done. Consider `2+2`; precedence won't help disambiguate that from `2 implicit-multiply +2`

Comment: I [answered this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33200946/1566221) in StackOverflow where it was originally asked. I don't believe "how do I use bison precedence declarations" really qualifies as a theoretical CS issue.

Comment: [Also posted on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33196809/781723).
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted. If you don't get a satisfying answer after a week or so, feel free to flag for migration.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was cross-posted on multiple Stack Exchange sites, which violates Stack Exchange rules.  The copy on Stack Overflow was answered, so it seems appropriate to close the copy here.